# Resource limit for k8s pods that consumes lots of resources at starting up, but minimal when running

Tags: kubernetes, resources, limit

My application consumes a lot of resources during it's start up, like preparing the data structures and files. However, once it's done, it consumes minimal resources during it's course of running.

Is there any strategy to configure the pod's resource limits in a Kubernetes cluster to deal with this kind of situation?

When I give it too little, it fails to start; when I give it too much, it's such a waste.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is embarrassing, I set the readinessProbe to just 15secs, which is ok for higher resource limits but not enough for lower ones.

Lengthen this one solves the problem.